# Memory consumption - Appdelegate's windows root viewcontroller

Tags: memory-management, swift3, logout

I have reassigned the windows rootviewcontroller when logout the app. My question is if I do like this, all the navigationcontroller and its stack will be cleared out or it remains in memory. This is the code

```
if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate, let window = delegate.window, let loginVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateInitialViewController() {

            window.rootViewController = loginVC
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes all navigationController and its stack removed**, because there can be only one root view controller per window, and because the window retains it. When a new view controller is assigned as root, it is retained and the old one is released.